# Clashing/Crashing Account class with MessageUI framework's account class

Tags: ipad, email, account, messageui

I am having an issue with my code, specifically the "Account" class. I need to use messageUI framework, but they are clashing with each other so I have renamed my `Account` class to `CustAccount`, but still I am getting the same error messages:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Account initWithCoder:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6069560'

Have anyone here found solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it seems the case that MessageUI has class Account declared inside it, so if you are going to use this framework, don't name your class Account.